# How to PInvoke in C# an array of structs inside another struct

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

From C#.NET I'm trying to PInvoke a method from a C++ assembly (no access to source) with this signature

```
result_code get_values(values_report_type *values_report)
```

Where `values_report` is a pointer to a struct of `values_report_type` containing the values I am querying which are returned by the method. The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int countOfValues;
    values_type* values;
    const char* name;
} values_report_type;
```

Where `values` is an **array** of struct `values_type`.

Here's what I would assume to be the problem: the C++ assembly I am working against gives me no information about the content of the `values_type` struct other than the definition

```
typedef struct values_type_struct *values_type
```

According to documentation this privacy is intentional.

So, my C# PInvoke looks like this right now:

```
[DllImport("MyLibrary.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern result_code get_values(out values_report_type values_report);

internal struct values_report_type{
    int countOfValues;
    IntPtr values;
    string name;
}
```

That works fine and gives me a pointer to the `values` struct, but what I need is to access the array of `values_type` structs and get a pointer to each of the items in the array (a pointer to each item is all I need since I don't have a definition for the struct contents). But I can't think of a way to achieve this, especially because the library has limited me in what it says about that struct (not even giving length). In C++ it would just be something like `values_report.values[0]` and so on for each item as defined by `countOfValues`, but I don't know of a way to make it work when marshalling it to .NET.

Is there a way to solve this in C# via marshalling?

Comment: `values` is not an array of `struct`. It is an array of **pointers** to `struct values_type_struct`. What are you meant to do with the elements in `values`? Reading `values[i]` is easy enough (`IntPtr Value = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(values_report.values, i*IntPtr.Size)`), it's what happens next that is not clear.

Comment: I worked a long time on unix operating systems and have read the entire UNIX manual a number of times.  Any structure/array you must be able to determine where each record ends.  Either by a fixed size object, a length property in the structure, or a terminating character like '\0'.Your structure is all fixed size objects so if you want an array then simply have one structure follow another in memory followed by a '\0'.  The only issue is when countOfValues is zero it will look like a '\0'.So at the beginning of the array you may want to add an integer of the number of arrays you are sending.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There are more methods in the SDK that use the pointer to the `values_type_struct` elements to perform calculations. So basically, I can't view the contents of the struct but I can send a pointer to it to another method for calculations and transformation.

Comment: That sounds right. If so, then it is what is known as an *opaque pointer*. In that case I think you have what you need now.

Comment: The best solution I can think of would be to try and generate an array of `values_type` objects by converting it to a byte array using `Marshal.Copy` then feeding it into a `BinarySerializer`. The only problem is that in order to do the marshalling, you would need to know the size of the amount of memory you want to get, so you will need to know the size of the array (presumably given by `countOfValues`) as well as the size of a `values_type` object (less obvious).

Comment: @jdweng Unless I am missing something, I can't accomplish this without the assembly source code to modify, which, as stated, I do not have. Or potentially writing my own C++ helper assembly to transform the struct into something else and then PInvoking into that.

Comment: You have *values_report which is an array of structures so you just have to add '\0' after last structure.  So if you have 10 structure of 8 bytes each (two integers) you allocate 80 + 1 byte ('\0') = 81 bytes.   Then copy data to allocated memory.

Comment: @jdweng No. It's an array of pointers. The structure itself is opaque.

Comment: The are two structures : 1) values_report_type which contains countOfValues structures of type values_type 2) type values_type which is an array of X by Y. Where x = countOfValue, Y = any size object which can be two integers (8 bytes).  No terminator '\0' needed since there is a length property.  value_type can be any size as long a the c# code and c++ code uses the same length object(s).

Comment: @jdweng No. `values_report_type` contains an array of length `countOfValues` of pointers to opaque structs.

Comment: I think it is one pointer to an array.  Not multiple pointers.  Multiple pointers would be **.

Comment: This is painful. Read the comments to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values` is not an array of struct. It is an array of **pointers** to struct.

Based on the comments, and looking at the code, it seems that you don't have a definition of the struct itself. This is what is known as an opaque pointer. You don't need to know the struct size, you just deal in the pointer to the struct, passing that back to the library.

Read the opaque pointer values from the array like this:

```
IntPtr Value = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(values_report.values, i*IntPtr.Size);
```

This obtains the i<sup>th</sup> value.

Comment: I may have missed something, but I'm not seeing where `values` is an array of struct pointers. I just see it being of type `values_type*`. Now my C/C++ is a bit rudimentary, but I take that to mean a pointer to a _single_ `values_type`, which can alternatively be used to mean an array of `values_type`s. Would an array of pointers not be represented by `values_type**`?

Comment: `typedef struct values_type_struct *values_type`. So `values_type` is pointer to struct.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not used to looking for typedefs. :P